# How to predict the pciSlotNumber assigned to a device by Vmware

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, pci

I'm trying to create a VM under VMware through the command-line. According to my current understanding of the subject, one step is to create a `centos-mirror.vmx` file containing the configuration of the desired VM.

Here is a MVE of this config file that I successfully registered but wouldn't start.

```
.encoding = "UTF-8"
config.version = "8"
displayName = "centos-mirror"
guestOS = "centos7-64"
virtualHW.version = "11"
numvcpus = "1"
memsize = "2048"
scsi0.present = "true"
scsi0.virtualDev = "pvscsi"
scsi0:0.present = "true"
scsi0:0.deviceType = "scsi-hardDisk"
scsi0:0.fileName = "centos-mirror.vmdk"
```

The image `centos.mirror.vmdk` does exist.

After creation of this file, I registered the VM with `vim-cmd vmsvc/register /path/to/centos-mirror.vmx`, which succeeds. If I try to power on the VM with `vim-cmd vmsvc/power.on <VM ID>`, I get the following message:

```
Powering on VM:
Power on failed
```

The relevant lines in `vmware.log` indicate an issue with the PCI devices (copying only relevant section by hand, because of an air gaped system...):

```
vmx| I125: Device scsi0 requested without secondary PCI slots available.
vmx| A100: ConfigDB: Setting scsi0.pciSlotNumber = "21"
vmx| I125: PVSCSI: scsi0: reqcallThreshold 0
vmx| I125: SCSI0: UNTAGGED commands will be converted to ORDER tags.
vmx| I125: PVSCSI: scsi0: h/w rev #2
vmx| I125:  Failed to register PCI slot.
vmx| I125: Msg_Post: Error
vmx| I125: [msg.pvscsi.badPCI] Unable to allocate a PCI SCSI adapter. Too many PCI devices are already configured.
vmx| I125: [msg.pvscsi.configFailed] Failed to configure virtual device 'scsi0'.
```

After a lot of trial and error, I found that adding the following lines to my `centos-mirror.vmx` file solves this issue:

```
pciBridge0.present = "true"
pciBridge0.pciSlotNumber = "17"
pciBridge4.present = "true"
pciBridge4.virtualDev = "pcieRootPort"
pciBridge4.pciSlotNumber = "21"
```

After registering the new VM, powering on the machine with the same command succeeds, and vmware.log contains a message about a missing OS (expected message, as not bootable device is plugged).

While I more or less understand why this additional section is needed, I do not understand why the `pciBridge4` must be configured (as opposed to `pciBridge5` or another), and why the slot numbers are set to 17 and 21. How can I predict these numbers from the host environment to successfully write a valid config file without having to go through a trial and error process?

Comment: Possibly related: https://serverfault.com/questions/220889/how-does-linux-determine-the-scsi-address-of-a-disk

Comment: Another hint may be this: http://faq.sanbarrow.com/index.php?action=artikel&cat=7&id=53&artlang=en indicating that `scsi0.pciSlotNumber` is set to 160 depending on the `virtualDev`. Then following https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2047927 we know that `pciBridge4` must be configured. But how can we find the value of "21" for `pciBridge4.pciSlotNumber`?

Comment: Looks like not indicating a `pciSlotNumber` parameter in the `.vmx` file is completely fine, as long as the `pciBridge0` and `pciBridge4` are enabled. That means I solved my problem, but am still interesting in having more details on how to predict the slot number "17" and "21".